# python: using a class to keep track of data used by another class

Tags: python, class

I'm learning Python via book and internet.  I'm trying to keep score of a game in a separate class.  In order to test my idea, i've constructed a simple example.  It looks too complicated for some reason.  Is there a simpler/better/more Pythonic way to do this?

My code is as follows:

```
import os

class FOO():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def account(self, begin, change):
        end = float(begin) + float(change)
        return (change, end)        

class GAME():
    def __init_(self):
        pass

    def play(self, end, game_start):
        os.system("clear")
        self.foo = FOO()

        print "What is the delta?"
        change = raw_input('> ')

        if game_start == 0:
            print "What is the start?"
            begin = raw_input('> ')
        else:
            begin = end

        change, end = self.foo.account(begin, change)
        print "change = %r" % change
        print "end = %r" % end

        print "Hit enter to continue."
        raw_input('> ')

        self.play_again(end, game_start)    

    def play_again(self, end, game_start):

        print "Would you like to play again?"
        a = raw_input('> ')
        if a == 'yes':
            game_start = 1
            self.play(end, game_start)
        else: 
            print "no"
            exit(0)

game = GAME()
game.play(0, 0)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the question a better way and got what I was looking for here:

[python: how do I call a function without changing an argument?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12037908/1472743)

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would format your code:

```
import os

class Game(object):
    def play(self, end, game_start=None):
        os.system("clear")

        change = input('What is the delta? ')

        # Shorthand for begin = game_start if game_start else end
        begin = game_start or end
        end = float(begin + change)  

        print "change = {}".format(change)
        print "end = {}".format(end)

        self.play_again(end, game_start)    

    def play_again(self, end, game_start):
        raw_input('Hit enter to continue.')

        if raw_input('Would you like to play again? ').lower() in ['yes', 'y']:
            self.play(end, game_start)
        else:
            exit(0)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    game = Game()
    game.play(0, 0)
```

And a few tips:

- I wouldn't create a new class that contains only code to perform one specific task. If the class doesn't take arguments or doesn't simplify your code, don't create it. Your `Game` class is an exception, however, as you would probably add more code to it.
- In Python, classes are written in `CamelCase`. Global constants are usually written in `UPPERCASE`.
- `raw_input()` returns a string. `input()` returns the string evaluated into a Python object.

Comment: No problem. I didn't actually test the code, so it might not work, but that's at least what I would try to do to it.

Comment: by the way, the class I would use to keep the score would have more methods and it would be used both a couple other classes.

Comment: @dwstein: I see you have a comment in your edit. The parameters of `play()` are expected to be numeric, so there is no need to convert their types. In most programming languages, it is good habit to make functions and methods that do *one* thing very simply and throw errors if something goes wrong. Your code will become very messy if you try to enforce datatypes within functions and methods that are just working with those variables.