# python: how do I call a function without changing an argument?

Tags: python, class, function, arguments

If I have a function:

```
def foo(self, a, b):
    c = a + b
    return c
```

How can I call foo without changing c in the function?  So let's say I call foo in another function:

```
def bar(self):
    z = self.foo(2, 4)
    return (z)
```

and then I want to call foo again in a separate function, but I want c from the time 'bar' was called.

```
def baz(self):
    self.foo(?, ?) # trying to just get c, without any changes.
```

Basically, i'm trying to keep an account in class such that other classes can have access to the same account; just a simple balance, adding and subtracting money.

Thanks.

Comment: That makes absolutely no sense. `c` is a *local* variable, it doesn't persist across function calls.

Comment: based on your question, and your responses to peoples answers, what i recommend is for you to learn some python; http://www.learnpython.org/ maybe this can help or this http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide

Comment: Can someone explain why I got a negative vote on this question?  I don't get what distinguishes this as a bad question.  I don't want to waste people's time, but I often find the documentation very theoretical with relatively few examples.  So, when I get stuck, I go here.  How can I improve my questions?

Comment: Looks like your negative votes where for been "too much off the track" :-) Don't be shy - your question is the key to understand the differences between "structured" and "object oriented" question - in the sense that what you want can only be done properly using objects. Just be shure to understand what is going on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've taken what Rohan provided for an answer and come up with the following. It seems to work, although there may be a better/preferred way to accomplish this.

The following code allows me to keep track an account balance across multiple classes and methods.

```
import os

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.stored_end = 0

    def account(self, a, b):
        c = float(a) + b
        print a
        print b
        print c
        self.stored_end = c
        print self.stored_end

    def testy(self, q, v):
        print "\n"
        print " _ " * 10
        z = float(q) + v
        print self.stored_end   
        self.stored_end = self.stored_end + z
        print " _ " * 10
        print self.stored_end

class Bar():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def zippy(self, a, b):
        print " _ " * 10
        print "this is zippy"
        foo.testy(a, b)

class Baz():
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def cracky(self, g, m):
        y = g + m
        print " _ " * 10
        print "calling stored_end"
        foo.stored_end = foo.stored_end + y
        print " _ " * 10
        print "this is cracky"
        print "y = %r" % y
        print foo.stored_end    

os.system("clear")      
foo = Foo()
foo.account(5, 11)
foo.testy(100, 100)
bar = Bar()
bar.zippy(10, 100)
baz = Baz()
baz.cracky(1000, 1)
```

Comment: Perfectly acceptable (indeed, encouraged) to share a final result you've produced based on another person's answer! (You're also allowed to accept your own answer if you think it should be marked as the complete solution for future readers.) You should just avoid treating it as a continuation of your question. If you have further issues with your implementation, you should feel free to post a new question. (And if you're looking for "improvement" advice, you may want to check out [CodeReview.SE].)

Answer (score 5):

Store `c` as class variable or global and override the function to return old value.

e.g.

```
class SomeClass:
     def foo(self, a=None, b=None):
        if a and b:
            c = a + b
            self.stored_c = c
            return c
        return self.stored_c
```

Note: you will have to handle when to update `stored_c` and any concurrency issues.

Update: WRT *glglgl*'s comment, updated for method overloading.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer.  A big help.  What do you mean, however, when you say 'handle" and 'concurrency' issues?  Thanks again.

Comment: @dwstein, e.g. if you have multiple threads updating `c` you need to use mutex/locks etc.

Comment: @Rohan THis surely won't work. Your first `foo()` is overwritten with the second one, making it inaccessible. Method overloading does not work this way in Python.

Comment: @glglgl, yeah! thanks for pointing that out. Updated answer to overcome that.

Answer (score 3):

`c` is local to the function and not static. That means that every time the function *exits*, `c` gets garbage collected. Why don't you just store the value of `c` as computed the first time? It seems like the obvious answer.

Comment: Agreed, I don't really understand why the answers below involve so much complexity like the use of decorators. In the OP the function baz just shouldn't exist because what the OP wants is just the value c so no evaluation of any kind is necessary...

Comment: I think I ended up doing what @Joel suggested.  Please have a look at my answer below and let me know if i'm close.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to have some construct to save the last result. E.g., you can do some wrapper to the function which does

```
def keep_result(func):
    from functools import wraps
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*a, **k):
        res = func(*a, **k)
        wrapper.last_result = res
        return res
    wrapper.func = func # makes it easy to bypass
    return wrapper
```

This is a so-called "decorator function".

Now if you do

```
@keep_result
def foo(self, a, b)
    c = a + b
    return c
```

the function `foo` (itself, not its result!) is used as an argument for `keep_result()` which creates a new function `wrapper()` which calls the original function, saves its result into an attribute and returns the result. This new function is returned in place of the original function `foo()`.

So you can say

```
normal_result = foo(whatever)
```

and then do

```
saved_result = foo.last_result
```

and you get the same.

Comment: Thanks, but this is way over my head. Any further detail you could provide would be greatly appreciated.  If it's not already apparent, i am a very new beginner.

Answer (score 1):

why not store the result in `self`, and have optional arguments to see if it should to any calculations?

Something like:

```
def foo(self, *args):
    if args:
        self.c = 0
        for value in args:
            self.c += value

    # In case `self.c` is not set yet, then use default of `0`
    return getattr(self, 'c', 0)
```

Now if you call `foo` with arguments, it will add all arguments and store it. If called with no arguments it will return the last stored value.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the thing you want is a cached property. You can make a decorator implementing descriptor that does that for you as a generic thing to use in future:

```
def cachedproperty(f):
    """Cached property.

    Calculated once - serves forever.
    """

    def get(self):
        try:
            return self._properties[f]
        except AttributeError:
            self._properties = {}
            self._properties[f] = f(self)
            x = self._properties[f]
            return x
        except KeyError:
            x = self._properties[f] = f(self)
            return x

    return property(get)
```

Let's look at the example:

```
 class X(object):
     x = 0

     def __init__(self, x):
         self.x = x

     @cachedproperty
     def y(self):
         return self.x + 6
```

Here are some tests.

```
 >>> ob = X(5)
 >>> ob.y
 11
 >>> ob.x = 10
 >>> ob.y
 11
```